# Regex for 'rec-01-' to select jobs in Jenkins view

Tags: regex, jenkins

I am setting up a Jenkins view and want to use Regex to automatically select matched jobs. The jobs to be selected all have a prefix like 'rec-01-', 'rec-24-', 'rec-98-', etc. The only difference is the two digits.

I tried with this regex `^(rec-[0-9]+-)` and many similar ones but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure, the string starts with 'rec' ?

Comment: I think Jenkins does a full match, so this should work: `rec-[0-9]+-.*`

Comment: @zett42 Why don't you respond so I can accept as the answer

Comment: Please define "_but no luck_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins tries to do a full match of the regular expression against the job names, so the following should work:

```
rec-[0-9]+-.*
```

Comment: BTW, one regex guru pointed to me that I should append "?" to the end of this answer to make it perfect (greedy -> lazy). So finally what I use is `rec-[0-9]+-.*?`.